# Java - File.exists() and File.isFile() returning true when file does not exist

Tags: java, file

I'm working in Linux, and I navigate to the "/tmp/" directory. I issue the command "ls -al" to list all files and their permissions and such. I'm looking for a file called "temp.txt" and I don't see it.

I then run a program that includes the following code:

```
String filename = "temp.txt";
File cacheFile = new File(filename);

System.out.println("cacheFile.isFile(): " + cacheFile.isFile());
```

This prints "true." "True" is also printed if I change it from isFile() to exists().

I navigate back to /tmp/ and list all files, and I still don't see it.

Why do isFile() and exists() return true? What am I missing about how this operates?

Comment: Are you sure you start this program from the ` /tmp` directory?

Comment: Quick insight, may be wrong, may be useful. If I recall, where you run your program is where new File(fileName) will be looking at. Check your main root of where your calling this program and see if temp.txt exists.

Comment: If you print out the absolute path of the file, is it what you expect?

Comment: I'm not running the program from /tmp. However, when I check the directory that I'm running the program from, I still don't see "temp.txt".

Comment: Did your program complete normally? Does it contain any write operations before the print statement? Did you explicitly close the file?

Comment: It seems that you are either running from a directory other than /tmp, or you are creating the file before that code is executing

Comment: Try adding the following statement to see which file your code is finding: `System.out.println("cacheFile: " + cacheFile.getAbsolutePath());`

Comment: Well, this is going to sound strange, but now it's working. You all were correct in the assumption that I wasn't executing this program from within the /tmp directory. However, the only thing I changed was to add "cacheFile.getAbsolutePath()" which prints "/tmp/temp.txt". Now, it prints "false" when I print isFile() and I can see temp.txt when I navigate to /tmp. What happened??